# array of pointers to ints? or pointer to an array of ints?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have noticed that pointers are 4 bytes while ints are 2 bytes.  When I make a declaration such as:

```
int * myGreatArray[50];
```

am I declaring an array of 50 pointers to ints?  I thought I was declaring a pointer to an array of integers, which is functionally the same as

```
int ** myGreatArray = malloc(50 * sizeof(int *));
```

However, I was informed by this tutorial that such a declaration is actually creating an array of pointers to ints, which seems more inefficient than just simply storing the ints themselves.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Check out [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*+myGreatArray%5B50%5D%3B). It's a tool that explains C declarations in English.

Comment: How do you define efficiency? You also forget that each pointer in any individual array cell can hold the address of an entire buffer.

Comment: What makes you think `int`s are 2 bytes long? This is rather unusual nowadays, but possible. What is your platform?

Comment: Small nit - sizes of pointers and ints vary across platforms

Comment: `int**` is not a pointer to an array. It is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. BTW, in the `malloc`, you mean `sizeof(int*)` instead of `sizeof(int)`, right?

Comment: Beware that a pointer to an array is **not** the same as double pointer.

Comment: _am I declaring an array of 50 pointers to ints?_ Yes.

Comment: Also remember that `malloc` returns a `void *`, so it is a single pointer not a double pointer like you used it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a question of precedence of operators.

```
int * myGreatArray[50]; // array of 50 pointers to int
int (*ptArray)[50];     // pointer to array of 50 ints
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping I'd discover, so when passing an array into a function, is it more efficient to pass a pointer to an array as opposed to an array of pointers?  I'd think yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
int * myGreatArray[50];
```

is indeed creating an array of pointers to `int`.  If you wanted a pointer to an array of `int`, it would be written as

```
int (*myGreatArray)[50];
```

> However, I was informed by this tutorial that such a declaration is actually creating an array of pointers to ints, which seems more inefficient than just simply storing the ints themselves.

Depends on what you are trying to do.  It's useful for creating "jagged" 2D arrays, where each "row" can be a different length:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
  myGreatArray[i] = malloc( sizeof *myGreatArray[i] * some_length(i) );
```

where `some_length(i)` represents the number of elements for a particular "row".  It can also be used to point to existing arrays:

```
int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};
int bar[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
...
int *myGreatArray[] = {foo, bar, ...};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing this declaration:

```
int * myGreatArray[50];
```

its the same as writing -

```
int ** myGreatArray = malloc(50 * sizeof(int *));
```

and you will get an array of 50 pointers to int, while if you will use this line:

```
int myGreatArray[50];
```

or:

```
int* myGreatArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*50)
```

you will get an array of 50 int variables.
I hope that my comment was helpful for you :D
and if you still have questions ask and i will answer you ASAP.
Have a great day ;)

Comment: When I wrote int** myGreatArray = malloc(50*sizeof(int*)); it should have been int** myGreatArray=(int**)malloc(50*sizeof(int*));

Answer (score 1):

**Declaring an array:**

```
int * myGreatArray[50];
```

This is an array that stores 50 pointers to `int`.  Be aware that it does not allocate the storage for those integers, just for the storage of the pointers.

```
int arr[50];       //array of 50 integers
int * parr = arr;  /*pointer to an int, which may be
                     the beginning of an array*/
```

**Passing to a function:**

> This is exactly what I was hoping I'd discover, so when passing an array into a function, is it more efficient to pass a pointer to an array as opposed to an array of pointers? I'd think yes. – Michael Hackman

The two function definitions:

```
void doStuffToArray(int ** array, size_t len)
{
  //dostuff
}
```

and

```
void doStuffToArray(int * array[], size_t len)
{
  //dostuff
}
```

are functionally identical.  When you pass an array, the function actually receives a pointer to the array.

To call the functions, you can pass the array (devolves to pointer to the beginning of the array, (*recommended*) or a pointer to the beginning of the array (*not recommended* for full arrays, but is useful to pass pointers to sections of arrays):

```
int arr[10] = {};
doStuffToArray(arr,     sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); //functionally identical
doStuffToArray(&arr[0], sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); //functionally identical
```

When passing an array of pointers, there are two function definitions that can be used, e.g. argv is an array of pointers to char arrays:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){return 0;} //functionally identical
int main(int argc, char ** argv ){return 0;} //functionally identical
```

My advice is to use the array notation (with the `[]`) as this is a declaration of intent, instead of the equivalent but more ambiguous pointer notation.

If you know how big the array is, then `argv` could have been defined as an 'array of arrays' `char argv[][]` which would be great, but can't be done. When defining a function, only the first array dimension can be undefined, any further dimensions have to be defined.   If you know how big it is though, there is nothing to stop you from creating a function:

```
void doStuffToMyArray( int array[][10]){
    /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact in this call

```
malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

there is allocated neither array.:) There is allocated an extent of memory. You can interpret it in various ways.

For example you can write

```
int *myGreatArray =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));

char *myGreatArray =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

or even like

```
long *myGreatArray =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

provided that `sizeof( long )` is equal to `2 * sizeof( int )`.

or like

```
int ( *myGreatArray )[50] =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

The only requirement is that there was allocated enough memory for the object(s) you are going to store there.

If you want to allocate dynamically an extent of memory for an array similar to this declaration

```
int * myGreatArray[50];
```

then you should write

```
int ** myGreatArray = malloc(50 * sizeof(int *));
^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^
```

If you want to allocate dynamically an extent of memory for an array similar to this declaration

```
int myGreatArray[50];
```

that is an array of 50 objects of type `int` then you should write

```
int * myGreatArray = malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
^^^^^                                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: `char *myGreatArray =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));` ? Really?

Comment: @Baldrickk It is a valid statement. The function malloc only allocates an extent of memory of the specified size. It knows nothing about what object of what type will occupy the memory.

Comment: Sure, but this will (probably) allocate 4* as much as you need.

Comment: @Baldrickk It allocates 50 * sizeof( int ) bytes  that can be used by a character array.

Comment: but 50 pints is 4* the size of 50 chars.  If you only want a 50 element char array, then you are wasting 75% of the allocated space.

Comment: @Baldrickk I dok not understand what memory are wasting. For example the user decided to allocate a character buffer that can store images of 50 integers. And what? Your comments do not make any sense.

Comment: Ok, If I were to build a car park that is only ever meant to hold up to 50 cars.  Nothing else, and no more, then I would want to build a car park large enough for those 50 cars.  If instead I were to build it large enough for 50 articulated lorries, then the car park would be bigger than needed - lorries take up a lot more space than cars.  If I were to put up to 50 cars in the lorry park, then there would be excess unused space that would be wasted, and in order to build it, I would have to buy more land than the smaller car park wold need.

Comment: It's the same with memory, if you want to store 50 chars, and create an array with enough space for 50 ints, the array is bigger than is needed (and an int typically takes four times as many bits, so that's quite a big difference).  Also, now I look again; there is a greater sin: `long *myGreatArray =  malloc(50 * sizeof(int));`  `long` is, on some sytems **bigger** than `int`.  If you try and store 50 `long` values in there, you are going to index outside of the array.

Comment: @Baldrickk Who wants too store 50 chars?! Why are you fantasizing?!  It is clear return in my answer that an allocated memory of the fixed size equal to 50 * sizeof( int ) can be interpreted differently. Your comments are meaningless and are not related to my answer.

Comment: If you don't want to store chars in the array, why are you creating a char array?

Comment: In fact, the best way to allocate using malloc would be: `char *myGreatArray = malloc(50* sizeof(*myGreatArray));` which naturally allocates the right amount of memory for (in this case 50 of) the type you will be storing.  you can change `char` to whatever other type you want, and it will compile _correctly_ with no chance of sizing errors.